# Move mail after reply in outlook

Tags: outlook, email

I got the problem that some in the helpdesk is using the same mail to use one mail for the customers.

So my question: Is it possible to make a rule or something that move the mail to another folder after someone replied it, to avoid double replies.

Comment: An employee is using the same email to reply to a customer, instead of continuing an email conversation .. Is that right?
Then you have to educate your employee. Technology does not replace humans, or you could just fire the offending employee and use a machine to do his job.

Comment: no what i mean is that we have 2 employees in helpdesk using the same mail becuase thats where the customers write to. So need a way to avoid them both to reply to the same person without having to be beside each other and say who they reply to. So i was thinking of a folder where all the replied mails could go in without they have to move them all themself. since its alot of mails to move manuel.

Comment: In outlook there the little mail icon next to a message changes when someone replies. If they make a habit of looking to see if the icon changed they can know that it was replied. Really though, they should just move them to another folder manually, it only takes a couple seconds.

Comment: Sadly as I can see that little mail icon only comes up if you connect as exchange but they use thier own mail for that. But nvm I think I try what trevoke wrote in answer.
Thanks alot for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft Outlook 2000, there is no way to create a rule *which will act on the email to which you have just replied*. You can set rules to move incoming emails to folders, to delete them, to move sent emails, etc etc.. But it doesn't handle the thought "not the current piece of email but the RELATED piece of email".

EDIT:
Given your more detailed explanation, you need another solution. Moving the mail manually is one thing. Dropping the mail in a queue which will forward to the users, or from which the users can pull, is another. Having a generic "support@mydomain.dom" is not a problem -- and in general, something happens internally to distribute this properly, even if it's as simple as forwarding it to a ticketing/work-order system. Maybe something like 'spiceworks' -- free and open source.